# Print number and character in two different column from a single column in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

My table

```
create table tdata (val varchar(5));
    val
    a
    1
    b
    c
    dd
    ee
    f
    2
    3
    4
    5
```

--Output i want is

```
    Number    Character
    1            a
    2            b
    3            c
    4            d
    5            e
```

I have done this but the only problem is that i'm gettting null values in both columns in place
of character in number column & vice versa

--Query

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(val, '[0-9]+') as num1,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(substr(val,1,1),'[a-z]')as char1 from tdata
```

Comment: Why `val = 'f'` is absent in desired output? What must be added to desired output while adding source row with `val = 'xyz'`?

Comment: Use recursive CTE which divides the value to separate chars (or 5 separate queries which extract the char by number combined with UNION) then apply SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: yes i forgot to add f in desired result

Comment: can you explain by writing it in a query ? i have already tried using union but that doesn't help it gives result i a single column

Comment: And what about my second question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you put it, see if something like this helps:

- create two additional tables (using CTE) - one for numbers, another for letters
- fetch `ROWNUM` which will then be used to **join** those tables
- join them!

Sample data in lines #1 - 9, the rest might be what you need.

```
SQL> with tdata (val) as
  2    (select 'a' from dual union all
  3     select '1' from dual union all
  4     select 'b' from dual union all
  5     select 'c' from dual union all
  6     select '2' from dual union all
  7     select '3' from dual
  8    ),
  9  --
 10  numbers as
 11    (select val,
 12            rownum rn
 13     from tdata
 14     where regexp_like(val, '[[:digit:]]')
 15    ),
 16  letters as
 17    (select substr(val, 1, 1) val,
 18            rownum rn
 19     from tdata
 20     where regexp_like(val, '[[:alpha:]]')
 21    )
 22  select n.val, l.val
 23  from numbers n join letters l on n.rn = l.rn;

VAL   VAL
----- -----
1     a
2     b
3     c

SQL>
```

Comment: And what about the next rows? `'dd'`, for example?

Comment: What about them, @Akina? I was lazy to type everything the OP posted (as they didn't provide proper test case - CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements).

Comment: That is bad. If you add the next rows than your output will differ from desired one. Look carefully - `'dd'` in source produces `'d'` in output.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand! Should have been SUBSTR. Fixed. Thank you for the comment, @Akina.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
       SELECT SUBSTR(val, 1, 1) Character FROM tdata
       UNION 
       SELECT SUBSTR(val, 2, 1) Character FROM tdata WHERE LENGTH(val) > 1
       UNION 
       SELECT SUBSTR(val, 3, 1) Character FROM tdata WHERE LENGTH(val) > 2
       UNION 
       SELECT SUBSTR(val, 4, 1) Character FROM tdata WHERE LENGTH(val) > 3
       UNION 
       SELECT SUBSTR(val, 5, 1) Character FROM tdata WHERE LENGTH(val) > 4
       )
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Character) "Number", Character
FROM cte
WHERE Character BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d73cea57f30149dca76d1fdaf0e83f7)

Comment: `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` it gives this error on select Row_number line

Comment: @RahulGupta This was due to unquoted `Number` column name. Edited, fiddle added.

Comment: hello @Akina this is wrong it is not even printing the number column from table it just prints the row_number, what happens if there are number like this in table 7,8,9,3,4,6,5 1 ?